# Pi4j port for pcduino

Tags: raspberry-pi, java

Do you know any port of Pi4j for PCDuino boards or anything similar?
 I am particularly interested in I2C, oneWire and Serial reading.

Comment: Does this help: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/80724/how-to-control-pcduino-pins-from-java

Answer (score 1):

The GPIO manager  doesn't really help because it can only read/write digital pins. Pi4j offers native integration to many more features, like native I2C, Serial, GPIO interrupts, etc.

I have started porting pi4j for the PCDuino board at https://github.com/fsamir/pi4j

Don't expect a complete port, as it is not a critical project for me. So far I was able to allow I2C on /dev/i2c-2. Next step will be OneWire support.